# 01-libnvidia-common-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, 20.04, dpkg

How can I fix this? I am following this [guide](https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-ubuntu-18-04.html).

```
(base) mona@mona:~/Downloads$ sudo ubuntu-drivers install
ERROR:root:No flavour can be found in nvidia-driver-450-server. Skipping.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-command-line-tools-10-1 cuda-compiler-10-1 cuda-cudart-10-1
  cuda-cudart-dev-10-1 cuda-cufft-10-1 cuda-cufft-dev-10-1 cuda-cuobjdump-10-1
  cuda-cupti-10-1 cuda-curand-10-1 cuda-curand-dev-10-1 cuda-cusolver-10-1
  cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1 cuda-cusparse-10-1 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1
  cuda-driver-dev-10-1 cuda-gdb-10-1 cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-1
  cuda-license-10-1 cuda-license-10-2 cuda-memcheck-10-1
  cuda-misc-headers-10-1 cuda-npp-10-1 cuda-npp-dev-10-1 cuda-nsight-10-1
  cuda-nsight-compute-10-1 cuda-nsight-systems-10-1 cuda-nvcc-10-1
  cuda-nvdisasm-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-10-1
  cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-1 cuda-nvml-dev-10-1 cuda-nvprof-10-1 cuda-nvprune-10-1
  cuda-nvrtc-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-1 cuda-nvtx-10-1 cuda-nvvp-10-1
  cuda-sanitizer-api-10-1 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libfprint-2-tod1
  libglu1-mesa-dev libice-dev libllvm9 libllvm9:i386 libnvidia-common-440
  libnvidia-common-450 libsm-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev
  libxmu-dev libxmu-headers libxt-dev nvidia-modprobe python3-click
  python3-colorama x11proto-input-dev x11proto-xext-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-450-server libnvidia-common-450-server
  libnvidia-compute-450-server libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386
  libnvidia-decode-450-server libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386
  libnvidia-encode-450-server libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386
  libnvidia-extra-450-server libnvidia-fbc1-450-server
  libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386 libnvidia-gl-450-server
  libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-450-server
  libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-450-server
  nvidia-dkms-450-server nvidia-kernel-common-450-server
  nvidia-kernel-source-450-server nvidia-utils-450-server
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnvidia-cfg1-450 libnvidia-compute-450 libnvidia-decode-450
  libnvidia-encode-450 libnvidia-extra-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450 libnvidia-gl-450
  libnvidia-ifr1-450 nvidia-compute-utils-450 nvidia-utils-450
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-450-server libnvidia-common-450-server
  libnvidia-compute-450-server libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386
  libnvidia-decode-450-server libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386
  libnvidia-encode-450-server libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386
  libnvidia-extra-450-server libnvidia-fbc1-450-server
  libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386 libnvidia-gl-450-server
  libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-450-server
  libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-450-server
  nvidia-dkms-450-server nvidia-driver-450-server
  nvidia-kernel-common-450-server nvidia-kernel-source-450-server
  nvidia-utils-450-server xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 11 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
Need to get 139 MB of archives.
After this operation, 224 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-compute-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [21.8 MB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-cfg1-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [73.8 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-common-450-server all 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [8,772 B]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-compute-450-server i386 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [22.6 MB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-decode-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [1,102 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-decode-450-server i386 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [1,134 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-encode-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [38.2 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-encode-450-server i386 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [38.8 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-extra-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [38.2 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-fbc1-450-server i386 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [45.9 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-fbc1-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [48.5 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-gl-450-server i386 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [17.2 MB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-gl-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [60.4 MB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-ifr1-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [67.2 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-ifr1-450-server i386 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [60.5 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-compute-utils-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [121 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-kernel-source-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [11.8 MB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-kernel-common-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [18.7 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-dkms-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [36.8 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-utils-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [365 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [1,536 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-driver-450-server amd64 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [428 kB]
Fetched 139 MB in 42s (3,274 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 224176 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libnvidia-cfg1-450:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libnvidia-encode-450:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libnvidia-decode-450:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing nvidia-utils-450 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: libnvidia-compute-450:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 nvidia-compute-utils-450 depends on libnvidia-compute-450.
 libcuinj64-10.1:amd64 depends on libcuda1 (>= 418.39) | libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 (>= 418.39) | libcuda.so.1 (>= 418.39) | libcuda-10.1-1; however:
  Package libcuda1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-450:amd64 which provides libcuda1 is to be removed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-440:amd64 which provides libcuda1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 is not installed.
  Package libcuda.so.1 is not installed.
  Package libcuda-10.1-1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-450:amd64 which provides libcuda-10.1-1 is to be removed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-440:amd64 which provides libcuda-10.1-1 is not installed.
 libcuinj64-10.1:amd64 depends on libcuda1 (>= 418.39) | libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 (>= 418.39) | libcuda.so.1 (>= 418.39) | libcuda-10.1-1; however:
  Package libcuda1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-450:amd64 which provides libcuda1 is to be removed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-440:amd64 which provides libcuda1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 is not installed.
  Package libcuda.so.1 is not installed.
  Package libcuda-10.1-1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-450:amd64 which provides libcuda-10.1-1 is to be removed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-440:amd64 which provides libcuda-10.1-1 is not installed.
 libnvidia-ml-dev depends on libnvidia-ml1 (>= 418.39) | libnvidia-tesla-440-ml1 (>= 418.39) | libnvidia-tesla-418-ml1 (>= 418.39) | libnvidia-ml.so.1 (>= 418.39); however:
  Package libnvidia-ml1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-450:amd64 which provides libnvidia-ml1 is to be removed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-440:amd64 which provides libnvidia-ml1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-tesla-440-ml1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-tesla-418-ml1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-ml.so.1 is not installed.

Removing libnvidia-compute-450:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64.
(Reading database ... 224121 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-compute-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
(Reading database ... 224136 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libnvidia-extra-450:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libnvidia-fbc1-450:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libnvidia-ifr1-450:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libnvidia-gl-450:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing nvidia-compute-utils-450 (450.51.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-cfg1-450-server:amd64.
(Reading database ... 224078 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libnvidia-cfg1-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-cfg1-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-common-450-server.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libnvidia-common-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-common-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-khqbUA/01-libnvidia-common-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-450.51.06-key-documentation', which is also in package libnvidia-common-450 450.51.06-0ubuntu1
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libnvidia-compute-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libnvidia-decode-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-decode-450-server:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libnvidia-decode-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-encode-450-server:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libnvidia-encode-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnvidia-encode-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-extra-450-server:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libnvidia-extra-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-extra-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libnvidia-fbc1-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libnvidia-fbc1-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libnvidia-gl-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libnvidia-gl-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libnvidia-ifr1-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libnvidia-ifr1-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-compute-utils-450-server.
Preparing to unpack .../14-nvidia-compute-utils-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-source-450-server.
Preparing to unpack .../15-nvidia-kernel-source-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-common-450-server.
Preparing to unpack .../16-nvidia-kernel-common-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-dkms-450-server.
Preparing to unpack .../17-nvidia-dkms-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-dkms-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-utils-450-server.
Preparing to unpack .../18-nvidia-utils-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server.
Preparing to unpack .../19-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-driver-450-server.
Preparing to unpack .../20-nvidia-driver-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-khqbUA/01-libnvidia-common-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for mona: 
Setting up libnvidia-extra-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64:
 libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64 depends on libnvidia-common-450-server; however:
  Package libnvidia-common-450-server is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386:
 libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386 depends on libnvidia-common-450-server; however:
  Package libnvidia-common-450-server is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-cfg1-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 126) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 133) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 126) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/nonexistent'.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:amd64:
 libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:amd64 depends on libnvidia-gl-450-server; however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386:
 libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386 depends on libnvidia-gl-450-server; however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up nvidia-utils-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-450-server:
 nvidia-driver-450-server depends on libnvidia-gl-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2); however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-450-server depends on libnvidia-ifr1-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2); however:
  Package libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-450-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libnvidia-decode-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-dkms-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-450.51.06 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-48-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-48-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod........

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up libnvidia-encode-450-server:amd64 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386 (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64
 libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386
 libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:amd64
 libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386
 nvidia-driver-450-server
(base) mona@mona:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-command-line-tools-10-1 cuda-compiler-10-1 cuda-cudart-10-1 cuda-cudart-dev-10-1 cuda-cufft-10-1 cuda-cufft-dev-10-1 cuda-cuobjdump-10-1 cuda-cupti-10-1
  cuda-curand-10-1 cuda-curand-dev-10-1 cuda-cusolver-10-1 cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1 cuda-cusparse-10-1 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1 cuda-driver-dev-10-1 cuda-gdb-10-1
  cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-1 cuda-license-10-1 cuda-license-10-2 cuda-memcheck-10-1 cuda-misc-headers-10-1 cuda-npp-10-1 cuda-npp-dev-10-1 cuda-nsight-10-1
  cuda-nsight-compute-10-1 cuda-nsight-systems-10-1 cuda-nvcc-10-1 cuda-nvdisasm-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-1
  cuda-nvml-dev-10-1 cuda-nvprof-10-1 cuda-nvprune-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-1 cuda-nvtx-10-1 cuda-nvvp-10-1 cuda-sanitizer-api-10-1 freeglut3
  freeglut3-dev libfprint-2-tod1 libglu1-mesa-dev libice-dev libllvm9 libllvm9:i386 libnvidia-common-440 libnvidia-common-450 libsm-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxi-dev libxmu-dev libxmu-headers libxt-dev nvidia-modprobe python3-click python3-colorama x11proto-input-dev x11proto-xext-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-common-450-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-common-450-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,772 B of archives.
After this operation, 34.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 224697 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-common-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-common-450-server (450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-450.51.06-key-documentation', which is also in package libnvidia-common-450 450.51.06-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450-server_450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My sources.list:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Also, from sources.list.d:

```
(base) mona@mona:~/Downloads$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
total 44K
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Sep 19 22:01 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2K Sep 23 21:00 teamviewer.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Sep 23 21:00 nvidia-machine-learning.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Sep 23 21:00 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   80 Sep 23 21:00 cuda.list.save
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 23 21:00 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2K Sep 23 21:00 teamviewer.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Sep 23 21:00 nvidia-machine-learning.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  142 Sep 23 21:00 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Sep 23 21:00 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   80 Sep 23 21:00 cuda.list
(base) mona@mona:~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64 /
(base) mona@mona:~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list.save 
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64 /
(base) mona@mona:~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-machine-learning.list
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64 /
(base) mona@mona:~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal main
```

Comment: also https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GpBGDgYtNZ/

Comment: also https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yMDrnWqpn3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `pavlos` in Ubuntu IRC channel:

Initially, I did:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia | awk '{print $2}')
```

and

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep libnvidia | awk '{print $2}')
```

Not everything was removed then:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep cuda | awk '{print $2}')

$ sudo dpkg --purge libcuinj64-10.1:amd64
```

Then, again,

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia | awk '{print $2}')
```

and

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep libnvidia | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I tried with everything but no luck.

Comment: yeah no other solution on web worked for me. we are all thankful to pavlos